# How to keep the last string with the same prefix using make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

As an example, suppose I had the string:

```
FILES=APPLE=A PHOTO=P APPALE=APP NUMBER=N APPALE=APPL APPALE=APPLE LARGE=L PHOTO=PHO
```

I want to get is the following string:

```
FILES=NUMBER=N APPALE=APPLE LARGE=L PHOTO=PHO
```

I have tried using filter but none seem to provide a nice solution.

```
define uniq
$(eval _set :=)\
$(strip $(foreach w,$(1), $(eval _first := $(word 1,$(subst $(2),$(space),$(w))))\
    $(if $(filter $(_set ),$(_first)),$(w),\
        $(eval _set += $(_first)))))\
$(eval _set :=)\
$(eval _first:=)
endef
```

Comment: I assume there's an error in your example and you either left out `APPLE=A` from your results, or else you meant to use `APPLE` everywhere not `APPALE`.  Else I don't understand what you want.

Comment: I want to get the last string whit key=value, for exanple: A=1 B=30 C=124 A=false D=true C=1, the final I want get: A=false B=30 C=1 D=true,。 In a set of strings, the value of the same string key will replace the previous string value

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
# $1 values, $2 results
# expands to results
sift = $(strip $(if $1,\
  $(call sift,$(wordlist 2,$(words $1),$1),\
    $(strip $(if $(filter $(firstword $1)%,$2),$2,\
      $(foreach x,$2,$(if $(filter $x%,$(firstword $1)),,$x)) \
      $(firstword $1)))),\
  $2))

FILES = APPLE=A PHOTO=P APPALE=APPLE NUMBER=N APPALE=APPL APPALE=APP LARGE=L PHOTO=PHO

RESULTS = $(call sift,$(FILES))

all:;@echo '$(RESULTS)'
```

and:

```
$ make
APPLE=A APPALE=APPLE NUMBER=N LARGE=L PHOTO=PHO
```

The key to working with make functions is it's much easier if you think in terms of recursion instead of looping.

I should point out that this doesn't care about the structure of the words; that is, it doesn't treat the `=` specially here.  It's just another letter, like `a` or `b`.

Comment: But only based on my example can the code you provided receive the correct response.                                                                                                  `New example: FILES=APPLE=1 PHOTO=10 APPALE=A NUMBER=3 APPALE=240 APPALE=160 LARGE=false PHOTO=true`. The final result remains unchanged.                                                     
I expect:                                                                                                   `RESULTS=APPLE=1 NUMBER=3 APPALE=160 LARGE=false PHOTO=true`

Comment: That's entirely different than what your question asked: you asked "last string with the same prefix".  The values `PHOTO=10` and `PHOTO=true` do not have "the same prefix" because one is not a prefix of the other.  What you appear to really be asking for is the last assignment of a variable in a string of words of the form "<variable>=<value>".  As I said in my answer: _I should point out that this doesn't care about the structure of the words; that is, it doesn't treat the `=` specially_.

Comment: Yes, what I'm asking for is the last assignment of a variable in a string of the form "<variable>=<value>". For example, a complete string contains multiple identical "variables". What I expect is multiple identical "variables", including only the last assignment, while also retaining the different "<variable>=<value" >".

Answer (score 0):

```
include gmtt/gmtt.mk

TEXT := FILES=APPLE=1      PHOTO=10      APPALE=A NUMBER=3 APPALE=240 APPALE=160 LARGE=false PHOTO=true

compile-vars = $(eval $(subst $(space),$(newline),$(patsubst %,****%,$(1))))$(foreach v,$(filter ****%,$(.VARIABLES)),$(patsubst ****%,%,$(v))=$($(v)))$(foreach v,$(filter ****%,$(.VARIABLES)),$(eval undefine $(v)))


$(info $(TEXT))
COMPILED := $(call compile-vars,$(TEXT))
$(info FIRST: $(COMPILED))

TEXT := FILES=APPLE=1    FOTO=10  TEST=3*7
COMPILED := $(call compile-vars,$(TEXT))
$(info SECOND: $(COMPILED))
```

Output:

```
FILES=APPLE=1      PHOTO=10      APPALE=A NUMBER=3 APPALE=240 APPALE=160 LARGE=false PHOTO=true
FIRST: FILES=APPLE=1 PHOTO=true APPALE=160 LARGE=false NUMBER=3
SECOND: FOTO=10 FILES=APPLE=1 TEST=3*7
```

We are abusing the variable store inside `make` itself to execute the overwriting assignment. To be safe from interference with other (true) make variables, I use the prefix `****`. Notice however, that the order of the variables is not preserved, `FILES` may come out last in the list.

Notice also, that any text using `$` will run into problems as the `make` function `eval` tries to interpret this as the beginning of a variable reference.

[gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) is just there for `space` and `newline`.

Comment: I could sketch a solution in pure gmtt functions as well, if you need a solution which is immune to `$()` substitution

Comment: It's not that I want to filter out spaces, in fact filtering out spaces would be simpler.  what I'm asking for is the last assignment of a variable in a string of the form "<variable>=<value>".

Comment: @Y2go then you can use the above code, its doing exactly that.